# Disable then re-enable click function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a file upload system, after the upload button is clicked, the file is then uploaded through AJAX. While the file is uploaded I want to disable the click function that is on the "Select Images" button.
Currently this is the click function on the file-selection button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#file-button").click(function() {
        $('#file').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

That works fine, but I want to disable the click function in the progress phase of the XmlHttpRequest, and then re-enable the click function when I get a 200 response from the server. I have tried `bind()` and `unbind()` and it works fine in Chrome, but in firefox, during the upload, the button cannot be clicked, which is what I want, and then after I get a response from the server the button is re-enabled, but in firefox two file-selection dialogue windows open at the same time. This is because of the function above, and me binding the function again using `bind()`. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to enable, then disable the button without re-entering the code (function) of the click event.

Something like this would be preferable:

```
$('#file-button').disable();
$('#file-button').enable();
```

I have tried the `on()` and `off()` and they do not seem to work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SOLUTION** -- thanks to Eric

I changed my initial click function to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#file-button").click(function() {
      if ( $('#file-button').attr('disabled') == "disabled" ) {
        return false;
      }
      else {
          $('#file').trigger('click');
      }
    });
});
```

And I set the following to disable the button

```
$('#file-button').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

And this to re-enable it:

```
$('#file-button').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: I used this too but found that the `else` was unnecessary/redundant.

Comment: I needed to trigger a click event on `#file` when the `#file-button` was clicked. So the else statement was necessary.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, please refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122526/disable-button-in-jquery

Answer (score 4):

Disable the button using jQuery [$.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function:

```
$("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
```

Add a conditional to the click handler to check if the button is disabled:

```
$("#file-button").click(function() {
  if (!$(this).is(':disabled')) {
    $('#file').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Later on re-enable the button:

```
$("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', false);
```

---

Or you might be able to use the submit event instead of click, if there is a form involved:

```
$("#whatever-your-form-is").on('submit', function() {
  $('#file').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: I think you have a logic mistake with this line `if ($(this).is(':disabled')) {` how do I check to make sure that disabled it set to false, not true.

Comment: You're right. Edited to fix it. Just add a `!`: `if (!$(this).is(':disabled'))`

Comment: I fixed it with a bit of altering of your code, have a look at the solution in my question. Thanks for the idea Eric!

Comment: I preferred this solution but had some trouble with the "if disabled" statement. After changing it to this it works: `var attr = $("input[type=submit]").attr('disabled'); if (typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false) {`

Answer (score 1):

Try `Attr` jQuery function.

```
$('#file-button').attr('disabled','disabled');
$('#file-button').removeAttr('disabled');
```

**Tested Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#file-button").click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>

<input type="button" id="file-button" value="ClickMe" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The click function that I have in my JavaScript code is overriding the disabled attribute as it is listening to the click function.

Comment: Your updated answer doesn't work neither.
[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/onIFp)

Comment: You can have a look at the codepen, I can't share all of my code, but if you look at the codepen, what I want is something to put under the first click function that would disable it, and then after the disable function to enable it. Sorry if I am not making sense.
> Click function is set
> Click function is disabled
> Click function is re-enabled without re-setting the first click function again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer input button in order to disable button ,

Something like below

```
  $("input[type=submit]").prob('disabled', true);
  $("inpur[type=submit]").prob('disabled', false);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The click function that I have in my JavaScript code is overriding the disabled attribute as it is listening to the click function.

And by the way it is not a submit button, it is the file selection button that is just in a `<button>` tag.

Comment: Sorry, did I try with what?

Comment: else call it by class name

Comment: Sorry I don't understand it, can you give me an example of how this would be used in my case?